# Browscap doesn't seem to hide blocks on google chrome for android

Tags: blocks, javascript, theming

I have a [website](http://mechdeveloper.com/blog) where I write some web development articles in it, in the blog page, I have set a slideshow with Views because the most of the slideshow modules are useless (it's my personal opinion, I was needing that the slideshow shows the image the title of the article with its caption, there were no slideshow modules that can do that), I used a forked version of [Responsly slideshow](https://github.com/mechdeveloper/Responsly.js) (it's not the big deal but I liked it because it's really simple), unfortunatelly the slideshow looks pretty bad on mobile devices, I used Browscap to hide the slideshow on mobile devices and works great, but, Browscap doesn't seem to hide blocks on google chrome for android, I still don't have time to work on the slideshow, so, is there something I can do to solve this problem??

NOTE: I don't know the version of google chrome for android that I'm using, my cellphone is a galaxy S (international version) with cyanogenmod 9, I am not sure if it's a bug or if it's my phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Browsecap (AKA 'user agent sniffing') will always be error prone, because there are so many different browsers, all with different user agents.

Instead, consider implementing [a responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/), using CSS3 media queries, to hide certain elements based on screen width.

Comment: I Think I will use both, if one fails then the other (media queries) will solve. I didn't want to do that before because I wanted to prevent drupal of showing the blocks, not show it and then hide it, but well, if it's that so, I have no other option I think.